# Why isn't IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> assignable from SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

When I try to assign a SortedDictionary to a variable of type IReadOnlyDictionary, the compiler rejects it. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 using a C# project targeting .NET 4.5.

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx), SortedDictionary implements IReadOnlyDictionary. The decompiled library code tells me the same. In fact, the following code snipped prints "True" three times:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Does it implement? " + typeof(SortedDictionary<int, int>).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<int, int>)));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Is it assignable? " + typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<int, int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SortedDictionary<int, int>)));
var sorted = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
var readOnly = (IReadOnlyDictionary<int, int>)sorted;
var roundTrip = (SortedDictionary<int, int>)readOnly;
// use ReferenceEquals to check if there's any explicit converter complicating things
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Do they cast? " + (object.ReferenceEquals(sorted, readOnly) && object.ReferenceEquals(readOnly, roundTrip)));
```

So why doesn't this compile?

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<int, int> readOnly = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it was introduced in a version after 4.5. I don't know which one but the MSDN shows 4.6 as "current version" and there is no way to so 4.5

Comment: Interesting. Where do you see the "current version"? And in that case, should my code snippet print False twice and then throw an exception? It seems like at runtime it implements the interface, but at compile time it somehow doesn't.

Comment: It shows it [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mRMys.png). The reason the runtime implments it is because 4.5.1, 4.5.2 and 4.6 are all in place upgrades. The only reason you can't use a feature is because you told the compiler to not let you use those features. Change your project to use a newer runtime and it will let you compile (this may require upgrading visual studio versions)

Comment: Weather your code will return true or false depends on if you have installed one of those in place upgraded versions or not (I don't know which version added), but if you found a machine that had 4.5 that ***never*** had the 4.5.1, 4.5.2, or 4.6 runtime installed then yes, your code would return false twice and then throw a exception.

Comment: Makes sense. But I'm still having trouble figuring out how you knew that 4.6 was the version in which this change was made.

Comment: I didn't, I just knew it was not in 4.5 vanilla because of the compiler error you are getting. However, I did just check, 4.6 is the first version that supports this. I checked by making a simple test program that did `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, int> test = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();` and targeted .Net 4.5, I then tried 4.5.1, 4.5.2, and 4.6. The 4.6 version was the first version to not have a compiler error, so if a computer has never had the 4.6 run-time installed your test would return false twice then error.